# CSS height + why there are scroll bars on this plunker?

Tags: css

I have created a set of very simple css classes for the layout.

[**Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/K4Yr2bJfitvKY3I6qiFr?p=preview)

However, I am not able to get rid of the scrollbars on the preview.

It must be a very small and silly thing, but I am not able to get hold of it.

Comment: There is a margin on the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, add:

```
margin:0;
```

in your `html, body{` css style.

eg:

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  /*more code*/
}
```

Also, you've set your `menubar-left` to `height:100%`.

`menubar-top` is `50px` high.

This means that together, it's `100% + 50px`.

You can either set `menubar-left`'s height to `height: calc(100% - 50px);` or change `menubar-top` to a `%` then take that away from `100` and that will be your new `menubar-left` height.

This is what your code should look like after:

[**plnkr using `calc()`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BEY1JuJNdFpparomCElS?p=preview)

```
menubar-left{
  height:calc(100% - 50px);
  /*more styles*/
}
```

[**plnkr using `%`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MpexpuuM633aXsnctV9l?p=preview)

```
menubar-top{
  height:5%;
  /*more styles*/
}

menubar-left{
  height:95%;
  /*more styles*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a charm. Did not have any idea about body.margin. Also Chrome web tools did not show any margins / padding on body element.

Answer (score 0):

1. body has default 8px margin, so `body {margin: 0;}` - it's horizontal scrollbar
2. vertical scrollbar is because of `.menubar-left {top: 50px; height: 100%}` - total height is 100% + 50px. You can fix that with using `overflow: hidden`, top in `%` or another wrapper element

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8j6KH2nY7s7rhKlO26lk?p=preview)**</kbd>

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
  margin:0; /* need to avoid scroll bar as body has default margin */
}

.menubar-top{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 50px; /* 50px height here given so adjust this from .menubar-left which has 100% height */
}

.menubar-left{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;

  width: 60px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px); /* as you have given 50px height for .menubar-top to need to adjust this 50px with height of .menubar-left */
}
```